# ViewSonic VA2465smh Monitor Trailing

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I recently got a new [monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RPJOQQ8) for my laptop (*ViewSonic VA2465smh*).  It mainly works, however when I played a game, I noticed that things would trail when moved on the screen (*especially black-colored things*).  I am extending from my main laptop monitor, which does not trail even when extending.  The trailing makes games unplayable and is a major issue.  I am using Intel HD Graphics 4000, if that helps.

Any recommendations on how to fix this?

Comment: I have done some testing with it and figured out that the problem resides with the monitor.  The most likely cause would be the monitor could not keep up.  I have returned and bought a new monitor with a much faster response time.  Hopefully that will fix the issue!

Comment: Yay!  The new and faster [monitor](http://www.amazon.com/VS247H-P-1920x1080-DVI-D-Back-lit-Monitor/dp/B005BZNDS0/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1451600881&sr=1-1&keywords=ASUS+VS247H-P) has absolutely no trailing!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate your monitor's menu and check if there's an Overdrive setting that you can adjust.

Comment: There is no Overdrive setting, and changing the refresh speed also did not effect anything.